# i want constructor takes input again and again

Tags: java

here is code want to take input in constructor again and again .

```
//gas class

package gas.mileage;

public class Gas {
     int miles; // miles for one tankful
      int gallons; // gallons for one tankful
      int totalMiles = 0; // total mailes for trip
      int totalGallons = 0; // total gallons for trip

      double milesPerGallon; // miles per gallon for tankful
      double totalMilesPerGallon; // miles per gallon for trip

    public Gas(int miles,int gallons) {

      // prompt user for miles and obtain the input from user
      //System.out.print( "Entered miles (-1 to quit): " );
     // miles = input.nextInt();

      // exit if the input is -1 otherwise, proceed with the program
      while ( miles != -1 )
      {
         // prompt user for gallons and obtain the input from user
         //System.out.print( "Entered gallons: " );
         //gallons = input.nextInt();

         // add gallons and miles for this tank to total
         totalMiles += miles;
         totalGallons += gallons;
            if(gallons!=0)
            {
                milesPerGallon=miles/gallons;
              //System.out.println("miles pr gallon :"+milesPerGallon); 
            }
            if(gallons!=0)
            {
                totalMilesPerGallon=totalMiles/totalGallons;
            //  System.out.println("total miles coverd using gallons :"+totalMilesPerGallon); 
            }
         //use if statement to check if gallons is 0.
         // caluclate miles per gallon for the current tank
         // Print out the milesPerGallon
  // Missing Part A

// end of Missing Part A

         //use if statement to check if totalGallons is 0.
         // calculate miles per gallon for the total trip.
        // Print out the totalMilesPerGallon 

// Missing Part B

// End of Missing Part B

         // prompt user for new value for miles
        // System.out.print( "Entered miles (-1 to quit): " );
         break;
         //miles = input.nextInt();
      } // end while loop     

}
    public void setmpg(double milesPerGallon)
    {
        this.milesPerGallon=milesPerGallon;
    }
    public double getmpg(){
        return this.milesPerGallon;
    }
}
```

---

```
// Main start
package gas.mileage;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GasMileage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // perform miles per gallon calculations

      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

     int a=input.nextInt();
     int b=input.nextInt();
     Gas g=new Gas(a, b);
      Gas k=new Gas(60, 3);
      Gas l=new Gas(20, 5);


   System.out.println("vlaues are :"+g.getmpg());
   System.out.println("vlaues are :"+k.getmpg());
   System.out.println("vlaues are :"+l.getmpg());
   } // end main method 

}
```

i want here gas class constructor input not taking again and again , a`enter code here`lso not finding and average which is  totalmilesprgallon=totalmiles/totalgallons 
(Gas Mileage)Drivers are concerned with the mileage their automobiles get. One driver has
kept track of several trips by recording the milesdriven and gallons used for each tankful. Develop
a Java application that will input the miles driven and gallons used (both as integers) for each trip.
The program should calculate and display the milesper gallon obtained for each trip and print the
combined miles per gallon obtained for all trips upto this point. All averaging calculations should
produce floating-point results. Use classScannerand sentinel-controlled repetition to obtain the
data from the user.

Comment: call this constructor in a loop

Comment: remove while from constructor and call this constructor in that loop

Comment: you mean that constructor will be inside of loop?

Comment: is this good approach call a constructor call inside of loop?

Comment: yes while instantiating the object using that constructor you can use your loop try and see if it works for you.

Comment: plz give a simple example for me ..here

Comment: i am not get your point "  while instantiating the object using that constructor you can use your loop try and see if it works for you. "

Comment: `total` means expression. You don't need to foresee a property for `totalSomething`. Use functions instead. If you study Database Normalization forms (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#List_of_Normal_Forms), you will catch it better.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** (Compact Logical Structure: no calculators. Input miles and gallons and print overview per trip).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(moreTrip(sc, "Would you like another calculation? (Y or N) ")) {
        int miles, gallons;
        while ((miles = getInt(sc, "Miles: ")) < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative number");
        }
        while ((gallons = getInt(sc, "Gallons: ")) <= 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
        }
        System.out.println((new Trip(miles, gallons)).getMPG());
    }
}

private static boolean moreTrip(Scanner sc, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    String response;
    if ((response = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
        response = sc.nextLine();
    }
    return ("y".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
            ? true
            : (("n".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
                ? false
                : moreTrip(sc, message));
}

private static int getInt(Scanner sc, String message) {
    System.out.print(message);
    return (sc.hasNextInt()) ? sc.nextInt() : getInt(sc, "Please enter a number");
}
```

---

```
public class Trip {
    private final int miles;
    private final int gallons;

    public Trip(int miles, int gallons) {
       this.miles = miles;
       this.gallons = gallons;
    }

    public double getMPG() {
        return (double)miles / gallons;
    }
}
```

---

P.S. The scenario is not clear. So if you want to add multiple trip statistics to your class and make your calculations based on those statistics, you better make a `Trip` class, instead of `Gas`, and make a property `private final List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();` within a `TripCalculator` class with the appropriate functions (see Answer 2).

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2:** Full structure (Collecting multiple trip-details, using `TripCalculator` to print all details of a trip collection)

A `Trip` class representing miles and gallons used for a single trip:

```
public class Trip {
    private final int miles;
    private final int gallons;

    public Trip(int miles, int gallons) {
       this.miles = miles;
       this.gallons = gallons;
    }

    public double getMPG() {
        return (double)miles / gallons;
    }

    public int getMiles() {
        return miles;
    }

    public int getGallons() {
        return gallons;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.append("\nMiles: ").append(miles)
                .append("\nGallons: ").append(gallons)
                .append("\nMiles per Gallon: ").append(getMPG())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

---

`GasCalculator` class containing collection of (multiple) trips and functions to get total miles of all trips, total gallons used for all trips, and average total miles per gallon:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TripCalculator {
    private final List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Trip trip) {
        trips.add(trip);
    }

    public int getTotalMiles() {
        return trips.stream().mapToInt(trip -> trip.getMiles()).sum();
    }

    public int getTotalGallons() {
        return trips.stream().mapToInt(trip -> trip.getGallons()).sum();
    }

    public double getAverageMPG() {
        return (double)getTotalMiles() / getTotalGallons();
    }

    public void printTrips() {
        trips.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public void printAll() {
        System.out.println("\nSTATISTICS");
        printTrips();
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.append("\nTotal Miles: ").append(getTotalMiles())
                .append("\nTotal Gallons: ").append(getTotalGallons())
                .append("\nAverage Miles per Gallon: ").append(getAverageMPG())
                .toString();
    }
}
```

---

Just a test drive:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        TripCalculator calc = new TripCalculator();

        while(moreTrip(sc, "Would you like another calculation? (Y or N) ")) {
            int miles, gallons;
            while ((miles = getInt(sc, "Miles: ")) < 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a non-negative number");
            }
            while ((gallons = getInt(sc, "Gallons: ")) <= 0) {
                System.out.println("Please enter a positive number");
            }
            calc.add(new Trip(miles, gallons));
        }

        calc.printAll();
    }

    private static boolean moreTrip(Scanner sc, String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        String response;
        if ((response = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            response = sc.nextLine();
        }
        return ("y".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
                ? true
                : (("n".compareToIgnoreCase(response) == 0)
                    ? false
                    : moreTrip(sc, message));
    }

    private static int getInt(Scanner sc, String message) {
        System.out.print(message);
        return (sc.hasNextInt()) ? sc.nextInt() : getInt(sc, "Please enter a number");
    }
}
```

---

Then you can also add some power-tools to your TripCalculator, like for example:

```
public Trip toTrip() {
    return new Trip(getTotalMiles(), getTotalGallons());
}

public void reset() {
    trips.clear();
}

public Trip resetAndGet() {
    Trip trip = toTrip();
    reset();
    return trip;
}

public void resetAndContinue() {
    trips.add(resetAndGet());
}
```